# Gate array propagation delay times

Tags: cmos, asic

This is kind of a simple question I haven't been able to find an answer for.

According to my notes, propagation delay increases as supply voltage decreases. While intuitively I would think it would decrease, this is reflected e.g. in [this](http://www.eea.epson.com/portal/page/portal/home/products/integrated_circuits/ASICs/Gate%20Arrays/0.60%C2%B5m%20%28S1L30000%20Series%29) Epson ASIC features. I would like to know **why** this happens.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Propogation delay in a CMOS system is \$\approx g_m/C\$

- \$g_m\$ is the transconductance and has units of \$1/\Omega\$
- So \$g_m/C \approx 1/R_{eq}\cdot C \$    which has units of seconds

And actively biased transistor will have a \$g_m = u C_{ox} V_{eff} \frac{W}{L} \$

- \$u\$ = mobility in units of \$m^2/V\cdot S\$
- \$C_{ox}\$ is the oxide gate capacitance in units of \$F/m^2\$
- \$W\$ and \$L\$ are dimensions of the transistor
- \$V_{eff}\$ is the overdrive voltage - (\$V_{gs}-V_{th}\$)

As power supply lowers:

- \$V_{gs}\$ lowers
- \$g_m\$ lowers
- propagation delay lengthens

Once \$V_{gs}\$ gets close to the \$V_{th}\$ then the the transistor starts to operate in the triode region and slows down even more (lower \$I_d\$ -> even lower \$g_m\$).

Comment: What is \$R_{eq}\$?

Comment: @PhilFrost 1/Gm !  the 1/Req*C is to show parallel to time constant calculation, I should add that in.  Thanks for the edits for markdown, but they seem to be a little messed up.

Comment: also that should be \$g_m = u C_{ox} V_{eff} W L\$, right? Otherwise, the \$m^2\$ from \$C_{ox}\$ won't cancel.

Comment: sorry about that. ASCII math hurts my head :) I'll stop poking at it.

Comment: @PhilFrost NO!  W/L is how Gm is controlled in design. Un has units of M^2/(V*S)

Comment: Replace \$g_m\$ with \$I_{on}\$ ...

Answer (score 3):

The basic reason is that the output mosfet current increases when its gate voltage increases, so it can charge/discharge the output capacitance quicker, more than compensating the fact that the output capacitance is being charged to a higher voltage.  An important side effect is that switching power also increases.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in an integrated circuit scales linearly with supply voltage. Some things are fixed by the manufacturing process and don't scale at all, such as individual transistor gate capacitances and threshold voltages, as well as the sheet resistivities of the metal and silicon layers.

Since operating currents do generally scale down with supply voltage, gates and interconnecting wires take longer to switch as a result.